# How do I map an attribute that references a static instance using JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I wanted to make an entity class with an attribute that references one of many predefined instances of a class.

In this example I want Card objects to have an attribute that references one of four predifined CardTypes (club, diamond, spade, heart).

```
@Entity
public class Card{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected int id;
    private int type;

    public CardType getType(){
        return CardType.idToInstance(type);
    }

    public void setType(CardType cardType){
        type = CardType.instanceToId(cardType);
    }

    public static class CardType {
        String picture;
        String color;
        
        public static final CardType ClubCard = new CardType("club","black");
        public static final CardType DiamondCard = new CardType("diamond","red");
        public static final CardType SpadeCard = new CardType("spade","black");
        public static final CardType HeartCard = new CardType("heart","red");

        private CardType(String picture, String color) {
            this.picture = picture;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public static CardType idToInstance(int type){

        }

        public static int instanceToId(CardType cardType){
            
        }
    }
```

How could I implement this?

Comment: `CardType` (aka `Suit`) could be an enum, and use a [converter](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa#converter) for persistence.

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped me a lot!